# iterating a json response string?

Tags: javascript, json

How can i iterate my json string return from a Java file in JavaScript ?

My JSON string having the following hierarchy;

`ResponseObject -> SId -> SeId -> QId-> List of data`. I need to access that list of data by looping through it using JavaScript.

Comment: has nothing to do with Java, removed the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to parse JSON String or alternatively, you can create a JSON Object using the javascript `eval()` function.

Once you have a JSON `object` created, you can use dot notation to traverse your json, like

```
var value = ResponseObject.SId.SeId.Qid;
```

Where the attributes from the dot notation are your JSON key in the json string.

Comment: im havin a list of values in Qid . how can i loop thru that

Comment: If it's an array, then iterate it like you usually do with an array in javascript. Remember, the object can be manipulated the same way like you do in javascript, nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this notation: myobjet["MyAttributeName"].

```
for( var SId in ResponseObject ) {

    for(var SeId in ResponseObject[SId] ) {

        for(var QId in ResponseObject[SId][SeId] ) {
            var value = ResponseObject[SId][SeId][QId];
        }

    }

}
```

I didn't test it, but it should work.